# Excel Named range using *? in order to count only relevant cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, named-ranges

Would like to use named range in order to find all relevant values in a range. However after several differrent approaches it seems that I cant't progress from here. Using *? in countif formula in order to get all text or values in the range, however it does not count the last cell with a text in the cell for some reason

```
=OFFSET(DATAMATCH!$I$7;0;0;COUNTIF(DATAMATCH!$I:$I;"*?");1)
```

[image]

Comment: `OFFSET` would be volatile, try: `=DATAMATCH!$I$7:INDEX(DATAMATCH!$I:$I;COUNTA(DATAMATCH!$I:$I)+7)`, I plus 7 because of your header. Allthough I'm unsure what your goal is. Do you want the range to include the "-" values or not?

Comment: The dynamic range should only include numbers, inother word, no empty cells or formulas which show empty cells or other charecters which is not a value or text. The prupose of all this is to chnage this dynamic range by a combo box and then in the end fill a graph with names and values

Comment: So I assume column `H` is the list of names `Karlsson Jan .... Donoso Roberto` and you want to get a range that is of the same size but from column `I`. Is this what you are trying? Are the cells in column `H` below `Donoso Roberto` actually empty?

Comment: no there is formula down to row 35 and then empty cells. However the dynamic range should only extend to the last row with text or values, no formula. I think you formula is counting empty cell with formula in it.

Comment: If you have a spare column, you could try =COUNTIF(datamatch!I7,"*?") starting in row 7 and pulled down, to see which rows are selected.

Answer (score 1):

An assumption:

- Your range in column `H` are all these names
- Column `I` range needs to have the same size as column `H`
- The tricky part is that there are empty cells by formula in column `H`

So you could try the following (in my test a named range called `TestRange2`):

```
=DATAMATCH!$I$7:INDEX(DATAMATCH!$I:$I,MIN(IF(DATAMATCH!$H$7:$H$50="",ROW(DATAMATCH!$H$7:$H$50)))-1)
```

[image]

This way it's also non-volatile (or rather; [semi-volatile](https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2019/jun/microsoft-excel-volatile-functions-201920646.html)), which using `OFFSET` wouldn't be.

Comment: This helped, great help there! Now there is only the range in H column "tekniker namn" to be solved. Tried this =DATAMATCH!$H$7:INDEX(DATAMATCH!$H:$H;COUNTIF(DATAMATCH!$H:$H;"*?")+7) but did not work as it counts formulas also, Any advise here.

Comment: Im glad this helped

Comment: It's actually semi-volatile, rather than non-volatile, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Without the sheet's headings just guesswork, but worth trying changing that `7` to `8`.